# Why Null is not shown when filtering in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

When I apply a filter, in addition to removing the data I indicated, the `Null` is also eliminated:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding an *OR* clause to the [*Filter*](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066) so as to `Include` *[FIELD]* `Is Null` would do the trick:

```
Exclude Opened_product_category_1 IN PREUBA|PRUEBAS DE IMPACTO
                                 OR
Include Opened_product_category_1 Is Null
```

***NOTE***: if you are looking to *Exclude* `PREUBA` or `PRUEBAS DE IMPACTO` then the first clause would be:

```
Exclude Opened_product_category_1 RegExp Match PREUBA|PRUEBAS DE IMPACTO
```

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/63807ed0-2a56-49c9-a11c-7088e051e551) to demonstrate as well as a GIF showing the process:

[image: 3]]